# Mapping UGC or FIPS6 geocodes to polygons?

Tags: geolocation, coordinates, cap

I am looking to convert UGC or FIPS6 geocodes to polygons (or even rough lat/lng coordinates + radius). An example of the geocodes can be found here: http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/us.php?x=0

Anybody knows where I could find a mapping for these geocodes?

Answer (score 2):

The data used by the NWS can be found here:
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/geodata/

In order to actually get the coordinates from the data, I used the program OpenJump to save the data in the CSV format.

Comment: Which file did you use to do the mapping between FIPS6 and polygons?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer for June 2019**

The NWS Public Forecast Zones can be downloaded as a shapefile from https://www.weather.gov/gis/PublicZones

I used [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) to convert the shapefile to WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and exported to CSV using [WKT geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry). That resulted in a 122MB CSV file.

**Instructions for Windows QGIS 3.4.3**

1. Download and extract `z_02ap19.zip`
2. In QGIS, Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer... (or press Ctrl+Shift+V)
3. Source Type = **File**, Encoding = **System**, Vector Dataset(s) = `z_02ap19.shp` extracted eariler. Then click **Add**.
4. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiVGw.png)
5. [Optional] Right click the layer, Set CRS -> Set Layer CRS... and set the CRS to `EPSG:4326`.
6. Right click the layer, Export -> Save Feature As...
7. Format = **Comma Separated Value [CSV]**
8. Choose a file location.
9. Choose an encoding, usually **System** or **UTF-8**.
10. Uncheck "Add saved file to map"
11. Make sure all fields are selected
12. Geometry type should be **Automatic** (They all end up as Polygons)
13. Layer Options:

    - `CREATE_CSVT` = **YES** (Creates a single file that describes the field types, useful for re-importing the file back into other GIS programs)
    - `GEOMETRY` = **AS_WKT**
    - `LINEFORMAT` = **CRLF** (Windows) or **LF** (Unix), historically, but most programs now can handle both
    - `SEPARATOR` = **COMMA** (Up to you)
    - `STRING_QUOTING` = **ALWAYS** (Likely doesn't matter as the data won't contain quotes anyways)
    - `WRITE_BOM` = **NO** (Byte-order mark, up to you)
14. Click OK, and QGIS will generated the file which takes several seconds.